# creating ISearchResponse<T> from json string for unit test

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

is there a way I can create ISearchResponse to simulate return by elastic search from JSON string? I need to write unittests for my API. The API building the query has histogram, date filters etc and hence response will be as per that and I want to simulate that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize json into an instance of `ISearchResponse<T>` with

```
ISearchResponse<T> searchResponse = null;

using (var stream = File.OpenRead("path-to-json.json"))
{
    searchResponse = client.Serializer.Deserialize<SearchResponse<T>>(stream);
}
```

If this is stub data, I'd be more inclined to have a stub implementation of `ISearchResponse<T>` in code as opposed to deserializing json to create an instance; maybe a little easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to try this out. What do you mean by stub data?

Comment: Stub data is known data that is used in a test - http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: I tried doing this (using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResponse<TQuery>>) and property Hits was empty (although Documents had the expected 10 entries). Interestingly, DebugInformation was set to "Invalid NEST response built from a null ApiCall which is highly exceptional, please open a bug if you see this\r\n". My JSON string for this starts with "Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST ..."

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` will not know how to deserialize `SearchResponse<T>`, you **must** use the client's serializer